# AvalonDock 3: Data bound title of anchorable is shown in designer, but not when running program

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, avalondock

I am currently testing AvalonDock. I want to create the layout via MVVM.

I have the problem, that databound titles for anchorables (not for documents) are shown in the designer but missing when running the program.

I found [this example](https://github.com/8/AvalonDockMVVM) and recreated a much simpler version to reproduce the problem.

Here is what I did:

1. Created a blank solution with a WPF application inside
2. Added Xceed WPF Toolkit v3.0 via Nuget
3. Created this very simple viewmodel:

   ```
   namespace NonWorkingAvalonDock {

       public sealed class MainViewModel {

           public MainViewModel() {
               Pages = new SimplePageViewModel[] {
                   new SimplePageViewModel("Foo"),
                   new SimplePageViewModel("Bar")
               };
           }

           public SimplePageViewModel[] Pages { get; }
       }

       public sealed class SimplePageViewModel {

           public SimplePageViewModel(string title) {
               Title = title;
           }

           public string Title { get; }
       }
   }
   ```
4. Made my XAML to look like this:

   ```
   <Window x:Class="NonWorkingAvalonDock.MainWindow"
           xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
           xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
           xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
           xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
           xmlns:local="clr-namespace:NonWorkingAvalonDock"
           xmlns:dock="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/avalondock"
           xmlns:dockctrl="clr-namespace:Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock.Controls;assembly=Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock"
           mc:Ignorable="d"
           Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
       <Window.Resources>
           <local:MainViewModel x:Key="ViewModel" />
       </Window.Resources>
       <dock:DockingManager DataContext="{StaticResource ViewModel}" AnchorablesSource="{Binding Pages}" >
           <dock:DockingManager.LayoutItemContainerStyle>
               <!-- you can add additional bindings from the layoutitem to the DockWindowViewModel -->
               <Style TargetType="{x:Type dockctrl:LayoutItem}" >
                   <Setter Property="Title" Value="{Binding Model.Title}" />
               </Style>
           </dock:DockingManager.LayoutItemContainerStyle>
       </dock:DockingManager>
   </Window>
   ```

Now, in Expression blend this looks correct:

[image: Main window in designer]

But when I run my application, I get this:

[image]

I think I am missing something, but I can't figure out what, since the example from github runs perfectly.

### Followup:

I investigated the example and my code a bit more, and in the example, the author sets the data context in code behind. When I do this, it works for me, too.

Moreover, I did the following experiment: I made the `Pages` property privately writable, initialized it with `null` and used a `Timer` which sets the view models after one second. When I do this, I get the titles, too.

Comment: I don't see the reason for path `Model.Title` in your example. Where does the `Model.` come from?

Comment: I do not see it either, but for some reason, it must be written that way. Check the example I linked.

Comment: What bothers me: [`LayoutItemContainerStyle`](https://xceed.com/wp-content/documentation/xceed-toolkit-plus-for-wpf/Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock~Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock.DockingManager~LayoutItemContainerStyle.html) seems to target `LayoutDocumentItem`, but your style has `TargetType="{x:Type dockctrl:LayoutItem}"` so either I picked the wrong documentation or you picked the wrong target type

Comment: The `LayoutDocumentItem` is for documents, they bind differently, but I want `anchorables`.